# Why are the file sizes appearing differently with the ls command?

Tags: command-line, bash, files, ls

The command I'm running is: ls -alFs --block-size=1

The following is the output:

```
4096 -rw-rw-r-- 1 dkm dkm 320 Oct 5 15:28 QRN_1570310934.charbin
4096 -rw-rw-r-- 1 dkm dkm 320 Oct 5 15:29 QRN_1570310939.charbin
4096 -rw-rw-r-- 1 dkm dkm 320 Oct 5 15:29 QRN_1570310946.charbin
8192 -rw-rw-r-- 1 dkm dkm 8192 Oct 8 11:33 QRN_1570555988.charbin
8192 -rw-rw-r-- 1 dkm dkm 8190 Oct 8 11:35 QRN_1570556100.charbin
4096 -rw-rw-r-- 1 dkm dkm 340 Oct 8 11:35 QRN_1570556140.charbin
```

on the far left is the size output from the -s switch showing in bytes due to --block-size=1, but the -l switch's output sizes (6th column from the left) are radically different for quite a few files. I've been trying to figure this out and I haven't been able to get a definite answer anywhere.

My best guess is that the -s switch is giving me device blocks and the -l switch is giving me the actual byte size. That's what it looks like but how do I know for certain? The 'ls' man page isn't giving me any details as to how the size output for the -l switch is derived.

Any suggestions for other tools I can use to try to figure this out ... or better yet; if anybody actually knows, that would be even better.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Type `echo 12345 > /tmp/test` then `ls -l /tmp/test` and you will it is 5 bytes as expected.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The resulting file size will be 6 bytes. There's a trailing newline character.

Comment: Thanks I was typing from phone and not computer to verify test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-s` or `--size` option prints the disk allocation of each file while with the `l` option the size is printed as a byte count.

Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#What-information-is-listed

Comment: exactly what I was trying to figure out. Thank you. I suspected it was something like that but I couldn't find any documentation. So, thank you for the link. Much appreciated :)

Comment: You'll find a link to the full documentation in `man ls` at the very end.

Comment: oh - weird. That was the first place I looked. I must have somehow missed it. *shrugs* oh well. Thank you.